# js.erb file is not executing content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a Rails 4.1.4 web app and in one of my view I am sending a form through Ajax (remote true). I have created a file called index.js.erb and this is the content:

```
$('#search_results').html('<%= j("#{render("admin/clients/results")}").html_safe %>');
```

**Unfortunately this is the output:**

```
$('#search_results').html('\n
\n
\n
\n\n  \"Illu\n\n <\/div>\n
\n\n
Heading Empty<\/span><\/h1>\n\n
Message Empty<\/span><\/p>\n\n <\/div>\n <\/div>\n<\/div>\n\n');
```

The JS code does not seem to be executed. What am I doing wrong here?
I want to render out the search results.

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Try `$('#search_results').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("admin/clients/results")) %>');`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#search_results').html("<%= j(render "admin/clients/results") %>");
```

Comment: The result is unfortunately the same.

Comment: Mind posting the partial and file path to that partial?